# Spotfire Personalized link with just one table

Tags: spotfire

I have a table with usernames, country and the sales data, all this in one table.

How can we restrict access for users based on country using personalized information link.

I saw some tutorials with multiple lookup tables, but unable to locate one which uses only one table data.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Some screens of the data would be helpful. I can't fully understand what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your information link, use `%CURRENT_USER%` as the `Value` under the Filters box for the column which contains the username. Or, if you are using a procedure, it would be for an input parameter.

Comment: Thanks Scsimon, Great Answer!

Comment: No sweat @BULB  